# Can not validate an HTML form with php & Apache2

Tags: php, html, apache2

I have a form inside the footer, I'm running the php file at the localhost *127.0.0.1/form.php*, apparently if one uses php code inside HTML it will just be commented out. From what I understood at the PHP Documentation I need to run the php file directly.

The code is based on the [W3Schools PHP Form Required tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_required.asp):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<footer>
<form method="post" action="form.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><span class="form-error">*<?php echo $nameError;?></span><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<?php

// define variables and set to empty values
$name = ""; // The variable is defined at the global scope
$nameError = ""; // The error variable is defined at the global scope

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($POST['name'])) {
    $nameError = 'Name required'; }
  else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]); }
}

// The function that will validate the form
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data); // The data is stripped of unnecesary characters
  $data = stripslashes($data); // Backslashes '\' are removed
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data); // Converts special characters into HTML entities
  return $data
}

?>
```

If I left the text blank it wouldn't echo the error at the span, so I tried debugging it

```
<?php

// Debugging test_input($data)
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $nameError;
echo "<br>";

?>
```

No matter what I submit at the input, the `$name` is always blank whereas the `$nameError` is always *echoed*.
So I thought that maybe the function isn't returning anything, and I did a little more debugging

```
// Debugging without the function
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  echo $name;
  echo "<br>";
}
// Debugging after each iteration of whats inside the function (without return)
$data = trim($data); // The data is stripped of unnecesary characters
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
$data = stripslashes($data); // Backslashes '\' are removed
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
$data = htmlspecialchars($data); // Converts special characters into HTML entities
echo $name;
echo "<br>";

?>
```

If I introduce, for instance, `& \ a` my output is:

```
*a blank line*
Name required
& \ a
& \ a
& \ a
& \ a
```

Apparently the php built in functions aren't doing what they are supposed to do. `stripslashes($data)` did not remove the backslash and the `&` should look as `&amp;` after going through `htmlspecialchars($data)`.

I even commented everything inside `test_input($data)` so that it looked like this

```
function test_input($data) {
  return $data }
```

And still would get nothing. Any ideas why? Also, why is the function `test_input($data)` defined later in the script instead of being defined before (tried to put it before defining my variables and still would not work). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a typo: `empty($POST['name'])` should be `empty($_POST['name'])`

Comment: _"Apparently the php built in functions aren't doing what they are supposed to do. "_ - I can promise you that they are. It would be kind of a big thing (and well known) if they didn't. In your last code snippet, you're modifying the (undefined) `$data` variable but you keep echoing the `$name` variable. Those are two unrelated variables.

Comment: Thanks @MagnusEriksson, it is fixed. I forgot to ask. Any idea why the error is not _echoed_ at the `<span>` after submission?

Comment: Because you define and set the variable `$nameError` _after_ you're trying to echo it. PHP is a top-down language. If you want to use a variable, you need to define it _before_ you use it. If you enable "display errors" in your php.ini or check your servers error log, you will see some "Undefined variable"-warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You have a typo: empty($POST['name']) should be empty($_POST['name'])" @Magnus Eriksson

"Because you define and set the variable $nameError after you're trying to echo it." @Magnus Eriksson

Comment: Why was this downvoted? There's no way to close my question if it was answered at the comments? What I did was against the meta?